# SSL Badge not showing

Tags: security, ssl, web, ssl-certificate

I am absolute beginner in terms of SSL stuff. I searched through the internet and did the SSL Settings. But now as I open the HTTPS web site. Everything works fine. I can see the certificates and all for SSL. But I do not see the badge (SYMBOL of trust) on the web site. After inspecting UI element I can see that URL is there on the web site.

[image]

After inspecting UI element below is what I see. Empty span. Where is the seal/badge. I am beginner please guide me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a green padlock, saying something like "Website protected by a GoDaddy's SSL Certificate", SSL certificates don't work like that. If you implemented everything correctly, what you should see is a green padlock next to your URI in the address bar. That padlock that you're trying to get from GoDaddy will not provide any security at all, and if you're worried about users not knowing that they're under a safe connection, don't worry, any user who knows about SSL, will know that what really matters, is the green padlock in your address bar.

Also, as "Unbreakable" already said, adding external scripts can actually add security risks to your site, since you're assuming that external content is performing a safe operation, but if that script gets compromised, who knows what kind of new malicious operations could be performed, and the worst part is that you'll take that risk, but you'll not get anything useful in return.

Comment: I can see the Https and pad lock in the browser. All I want to know is why I am not able to see that Cerified/Secured image thing which I see in many web sites. The link that I have pasted returns an OK response with No Content. I thought I should be getting some image/seal of security. That being said, My web site is properly working on HTTPS Protocol.